# Is proper validating user input not sufficient to prevent sql injection

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

I know sql injection can be done if I am taking input from user like user_name and password. SQL prepared statement are advised to use to prevent sql injection but what if I am doing proper validation of input by user before doing sql operations..

in user name input field a user can try to inject by following way

abc@gmail.com or '1'='1'

or

abc@gmail.com; DROP ........(sql query to drop db, delete tables etc.)

but if I am validating user email and if email is not according to rule then no database interaction will be done.

like this I can also validate password which cannot contain spaces.

So my question is this if I am validating each input by user then can someone still do sql injection in my database.

Comment: In most well designed software there is a strict distinguish between parts of the software. see MVC and others. The database is responsible to ensure there are no SQL injections. Can you do it from client GUI part? yes. will it work? yes. But what if in two years someone else will change the GUI without knowing that it effects the DB as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because you can never be sure you've filtered the right stuff.

Additionally, you are severely limiting the input to your application if you're disallowing certain characters.

For example, imagine if StackOverflow filtered out `<script>` entered in its text boxes.

If you're disallowing spaces in passwords [I'll just set my password to be](https://xkcd.com/327/):

```
Robert');/**/DROP/**/TABLE/**/STUDENTS;--
```

Also, what if my [email address was](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/):

```
"' OR '1' = '1'--"@example.com
```

? (This is perfectly valid according to the RFC.)